# Why does GNU Readline's shell-expand-line command only expands the first occurrence of tilde (~)?

Tags: bash, readline

According to the Bash manual, the `shell-expand-line` GNU Readline command should expand the command-line, just as Bash normally would, including alias and history expansion.

The current setting can be seen with `bind -P | grep shell-expand-line`:

```
shell-expand-line can be found on "\e\C-e".
```

My issue is that only the first tilde (`~`) is expanded in the example below:

```
~/foo/bar ~/foo/baz
```

After pressing "\e\C-e":

```
/Users/nlykkei/foo/bar ~/foo/baz
```

Why?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. One that's even stranger is that `echo *` doesn't change anything but `echo $(echo *)` expands the list of file names in the current directory.

Answer (score 6):

If you look at its [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git), you'll see that `shell-expand-line` should be actually called `shell-expand-line-as-if-it-were-a-word`:

```
>> bashline.c
static int
shell_expand_line (count, ignore)
     int count, ignore;
{
     ...
      w->word = savestring (rl_line_buffer);
      w->flags = rl_explicit_arg ? (W_NOPROCSUB|W_NOCOMSUB) : 0;
      expanded_string = expand_word (w, rl_explicit_arg ? Q_HERE_DOCUMENT : 0);
```

```
>>> subst.c
/* Expand WORD, performing word splitting on the result.  This does
   parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion,
   word splitting, and quote removal. */

WORD_LIST *
expand_word (word, quoted)
     WORD_DESC *word;
     int quoted;
```

Notice that that comment doesn't include either filename or tilde expansion. So it's basically a fluke that it works even for the first tilde (tilde only has meaning at the beginning of a word, anyway). But that will also do process substitutions, which isn't mentioned either. The heavy lifting is in the `expand_word_internal` function in the same file.

The `rl_explicit_arg` in the first snippet means that if you press Esc-1 or Alt-2 before the key combo bound to `shell-expand-line`, no quote removal *and* process/command substitution will be done. Pretty intuitive, isn't it?

You may try submitting a bug report, but there are probably already thousands of similar limitations and special cases like this in bash.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the man page is a bit misleading then, because it says that the Readline command will expand the line like Bash normally would, or do you interpret the high-level documentation differently?

Comment: The manpage is lying. Try eg. with a line like `(bar=*; echo $bar)`, or simply `echo *`.

Comment: mosvy - will you be so kind to provide a link to the source code? :-)

Comment: Is http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/ the official repository for all (standard) Linux programs?

Comment: no, only for some programs. if you're on debian/ubuntu, you can get the exact source of the programs you're using (distro patches included) by `apt-get source pkg-name`.

Comment: the `bash` repo is a "dump"-repo: it's only releases and such: there's no diff-by-diff history.