# Bash expansion behavior

Tags: bash, alias, readline

I was playing around with the readline functions `shell-expand-line` and `alias-expand-line`.
From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Miscellaneous-Commands):

> **shell-expand-line** Expand the line as the shell does. This performs
>   alias and history expansion as well as all of the shell word
>   expansions ([see Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)).

My understanding of this is that `shell-expand-line` would perform all substitutions and expansions that bash would before the point of actual execution.

A contrived example seems to support this:

```
$ NAME="Adam"
$ alias ec='echo'
$ ec $NAME
```

If I execute the function `shell-expand-line` the previous command expands to `$ echo Adam`.

Where my confusion begins is with the following example:

```
$ alias cdspace='cd ~/path\ with\ spaces'
$ cdspace
```

Based on my understanding if I were to execute `shell-expand-line` the command would expand to `$ cd /Users/Adam/path\ with\ spaces`. However in practice it expands to `$ cd ~/path with spaces`. Executing `cdspace` either as is, or with `alias-expand-line` works as expected, however if I expand it with `shell-expand-line` execution fails.

The sub-section [Quote Removal](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal) of [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) does address this:

> After the preceding expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the
>   characters ‘\’, ‘'’, and ‘"’ that did not result from one of the above
>   expansions are removed.

So it seems like unquoted backslashes are always removed. To test this, if I manually type `$ cd ~/path\ with\ spaces` and then execute `shell-expand-line` it updates the command to `$ cd ~/path with spaces`. Furthermore, if I type `$ cd ~/path\\ with\\ spaces` and then execute `shell-expand-line` twice each execution it removes one set of of back slashes.

My expectation is that `shell-expand-line` fully expands the line to what would be ultimately resolved by bash internally, but this does not seem to be the case as it needs to be executed multiple times.

Where I am ultimately confused now is how `$ cd ~/path\ with\ spaces` correctly executes as by my understanding of the [Shell Expansions documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions), it will eventually be resolved to `$ cd ~/path with spaces`.

Comment: Apparently, the doc is not accurate about `shell-expand-line`, as shown in [this other question on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/535415/315749).

Comment: Setting tilde expansion aside: are you saying that, in your expectations, the `/p w s` path with spaces needs to be resolved by Bash into `/p\ w\ s` (including the backslashes), at the end of the steps listed in the "Shell Expansions" section of the manual, to work correctly?

Comment: I'm saying the opposite, that (to my understanding of the documentation at least) after all the other steps of expansion and substitution, bash will remove the escaped spaces such that  `/p\ w\ s` will get resolved to `/p w s`, and the behavior of `shell-expand-line` seems to support this.

Comment: run bash -x script.sh and see differences between single and double quotes for alias on debugging output

Answer (score 1):

I think the bash documentation is unclear here. As noted in another comment, the `shell-expand-line` documentation implies that *all* Shell Expansions will be executed, when clearly tilde expansion is not.

Additionally, the Quote Removal step does not remove unquoted backslashes still lingering after the first set have been pattern matched, contrary to what 3.5.9 (https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal)  indicates.

That said, I don't think `shell-expand-line` is intended to produce a command that can be run from the shell, if that is what you're expecting. Because it is performing all the Shell Expansions, which assume the input has *already* been tokenized, the pattern matching step will remove backslashes, making the previously escaped spaces 'unescaped.' If you try to run the resulting string, it will be tokenized *again*, and thus each space-separated word will be treated as a separate token.